# awk to remove lines with string...what if string contains line return?

Tags: awk

Trying to strip out lines in a file containing a few strings, this is working perfectly:

```
awk '!/string1/string\ 2/' file.txt > file.filtered.txt
```

Now I need to add a string that includes "string3" at the end of any lines.

Is it possible to add a string that includes a line return?

I tried these iterations but none worked:

```
awk '!/string1/string\ 2/string3\n/' file.txt > file.filtered.txt
```

and

```
awk '!/string1/string\ 2/string3\\n/' file.txt > file.filtered.txt
```

For example, we want to delete lines that end like this:

```
YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS criteria=value, criteria=value, tag=ABC
```

But not delete lines that end like this:

```
YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS criteria=value, criteria=value, tag=ABC (123)
```

Thoughts?

TIA,
Don

Comment: Post some sample data with expected output for testing, please.

Comment: Sure thing, for example we want to delete lines that end like this:

"YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS criteria=value, criteria=value, criteria=value, criteria=value, tag=ABC"

But not delete lines that end like this:

"YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS criteria=value, criteria=value, criteria=value, criteria=value, tag=ABC (123)"

PS, wow no way to format responses. :(

Comment: If you [edit] the question instead of adding to it in the comments, it's much easier to read.

Comment: Ah, gotcha, doing now. :)

Answer (score 0):

First a note: your example makes no sense, and will give you all kinds of errors from awk (syntax errors, "backslash not last character on line", "unexpected newline", etc).  I assume you really meant

```
awk '!/string1|string 2/'
```

which will strip out lines matching either `string1` or `string 2`.  These are just normal regular expressions, so if you only want to match something at the end of a line, use `$`:

```
awk '!/string1|string 2|string3$/'
```

which will strip out any line containing `string1` or `string 2` or ending with `string3`

Comment: Wow, why didn't I think of that?! :):):)

Comment: Chris you're right, for some reason I thought looking for line returns was the route to take. Looking for a known string at the end of the line is what I actually needed. The values we are looking for are masked, so it'll be something that isn't "string1" or "string 2". I made those up to show some values have a space. I updated the examples to make more sense.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, this worked perfectly...you folks are priceless!

```
awk '!/string1|string\ 2|string3$/'
```